# How can I change HTML tag's color in App.js file with IntelliJ?

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea

I want to change tag name's color in App.js file. I am using IntelliJ now. But I don't know how to change it.

I already tried this way. Preferences > color scheme > HTML > Tag name.

But it only changed original HTML file(such as index.html)'s tag name. It doesn't change HTML tag color in App.js File.

How can I change it's color? The image below is my App.js file code.

[image]

I want to change the underlined tags color! Yellow to red.

Answer (score 2):

*JSX* tags colors can be changed in **Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | XML**, **Tag Name**

Note that since 2021.3.1 you can specify a different color for custom tags (like React component names) by modifying **Custom Tag Name** there:

[image]

see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-52334#focus=Comments-27-5596272.0-0

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is really helpful!